# IE border radius makes the border and the background curve different corners

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

I have a `<div>` that has a `background` and a `border`.

I define `border-radius: 10px 0 10px 0` and IE makes the border round in the upper-right and bottom-left corners, and the background round in the other corners.

So I have two corners that have a square border and the background doesn't reach the end, and two with a round border and the background sticks out.

I should say when I add `direction: ltr` it fixes it, but I need `direction: rtl`.

If I specify `border-top-right: 10px` etc. it's the same thing. The border will be round at the wrong corner.

Comment: I wanna see this! I guess the solution would be to create 2 containers. 1 for the borders, 1 for the background... But it sucks a lot!

Comment: IE has trouble with borders and RTL.

Comment: open this in IE http://jsfiddle.net/CLwHt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does hacking around it count?

```
#div1 {
    direction:rtl;
    border:1px solid black;
    background:green;
    border-radius:10px 0 10px 0;
    margin:20px auto;
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
:root #div1 {
    direction: ltr \9; /* IE9+ */
}
#div1 > span {
    direction: rtl;
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Surround text content in `<span>`:

```
<div id="div1">
    <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thought about it, it's like what Armel L suggested i was hoping for something a bit more direct that doesn't make me add unnecessary tags

Comment: @DotanReis I would have thought a span tag is by far the least intrusive addition to solve the problem; semantics is maintained. Of course, the CSS is disgusting, but it does the job concisely...